# Does PyCharm 3.4 support PySide 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, pycharm

I am currently going through the familiar new language, new installation nightmare or fun if you so choose to believe.

I need to install PySide 3.2 so as to have support for PY-VISA which states that it only runs on Python 2.6+ and 3.2+. So I'm believing that it will also apply to PySide 3.2 which I am using. (If I'm wrong here, please let me know)

I am also installing the PyQt4 for Python 3.2

But what about PyCharm? The latest community edition I downloaded is 3.4. Does this mean it has support for just the latest PySide 3.4 or do I need an older version of PyCharm to work with 3.2 (which I can't seem to find)? Perhaps the version numbers are a coincidence. Just not sure. Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: for most python packages, `2.6+` means it will run on `2.7` as well, but not `3.0`. likewise `3.2+` should mean it will run perfectly fine on `3.3` and `3.4`, just possibly not on `4.0`, depending on the scope of the change if/when it happens.

Comment: Thanks so much pseudonym. I do indeed appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its compatible. I'm currently on PyCharm 4.0 (EAP) and it's compatible with all versions of python and associated packages. Its hands down the best product out there for coding with python